# How to convert simple height map to a realistic landscape

Tags: procedural-generation

So I have a simple height map, which is visualized using cubes. I'm wondering how I could convert this simple setup with cubes into more intricate terrain. I'm looking for it to look something like a low poly game, like this:
[image]
I'm using godot. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Presumably you've taken a triangulated plane and offset its vertex heights by interpolated heights from the heightmap? Did you need any specific help with that step, or did the output differ in some specific way from what you want? I would say your screenshot doesn't look "realistic," so it's unclear to me what the delta is between what you have and what you want.

Comment: The image i gave was an example of what I wanted. I don't totally understand what you mean, could you explain in simpler terms? Thanks! @DMGregory

Comment: Did you take a flat plane mesh made of triangles, and set the vertical coordinate of each vertex to a height from your height map?

Comment: The example image is very helpful, but the "like this but more detailed" part would benefit from a clarifying edit. More detail could be mesh refinements, texturing, or other things. Folks need some idea regarding what additional detail you want to add in order to offer relevant productive answers. Also, if you're using a framework, edit to let us know - some systems have built-in solutions for height maps.